# Create Mobile List through API [Solved]

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, list, mobileconnect, sms

I used Fuel-SDK to create a Email List through API and pushed the contacts in CSVs (SFTP) to that Email List in Marketing Cloud. I would like to do the same thing for the SMS, however the Fuel-SDK doesn't work for the SMS.

Is there a way to create a Mobile List through API (rest/soap) into Mobile Connect in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/importSend.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everything about RESt API for SMS I recommend you to check [THIS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/queueContactImport.htm). Try to import and post eventually the code here if this is not working.